# Number of records in a ListView?

Tags: xml, xaml

I've got a list view pulling in data from a database and I need to a way to count the number of rows, or records, in the list. The purpose of this will be to set the IsEnabled property on a button.

So if the number of records is equal to or greater than one, the button will be disabled. This has to be done in XML or XAML.

Comment: well assuming something like .rows.count or .items.count isn't the answer, we'll need a little more information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but lets try binding to the itemssource property ... give this a shot:

```
<ListView x:Name="TestingListView">
    ...
</ListView>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=TestingListView, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" />
```

Comment: That worked. Can also use '<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ListName, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" />'